# Horizontal Scroll Reverts to Original Scroll Position

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, ionic-framework

I have a simple horizontal scroll bar. Whenever I attempt to the scroll to the right and release the mouse click, the horizontal bar immediately reverts back to the original positioning. I have no idea why this is happening. I want the scroll to stick when I release the mouse click, not revert back to the original position. Code below.

HTML

```
<ion-scroll direction="x" class=" wide-item">
      look at dog    <img src="http://www.cdc.gov/animalimportation/images/dog2.jpg" width="70" height="70">
      look at dog    <img src="http://www.cdc.gov/animalimportation/images/dog2.jpg" width="70" height="70">
      look at dog    <img src="http://www.cdc.gov/animalimportation/images/dog2.jpg" width="70" height="70">
      look at dog    <img src="http://www.cdc.gov/animalimportation/images/dog2.jpg" width="70" height="70">
      look at dog    <img src="http://www.cdc.gov/animalimportation/images/dog2.jpg" width="70" height="70">
      look at dog    <img src="http://www.cdc.gov/animalimportation/images/dog2.jpg" width="70" height="70">
      look at dog    <img src="http://www.cdc.gov/animalimportation/images/dog2.jpg" width="70" height="70">
      look at dog    <img src="http://www.cdc.gov/animalimportation/images/dog2.jpg" width="70" height="70">
</ion-scroll>
```

CSS

```
.wide-item {
  width: 1000%;
  overflow-x: scroll; 
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; 
  display: inlnine;
}

img {
  display: inline;
}
```

Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOzmJL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `width: 100%;` instead of `10000px;`.

Comment: I've updated my question and codepen to match a better example of my problem.

Comment: I'm going to give you credit for this question and ask a new question since it's different from the old one I asked.

Comment: You have a typo under the .wide-item declaration... "inlnine;". If you want to display the content inline, you would then also need to use `white-space: nowrap;`.

Comment: Thanks. It's still not working on my app which is incredibly frustrating. Obviously there is a difference between my app and the codepen but what it is I don't know.

Comment: Yeah, hard to debug it without seeing it :-/... I suggest you try playing with the width declaration and display type of your content, etc.. Is the CSS in your app exactly the same as in the codepen? You can also try adapting other working examples... for instance: http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/HIuft